# How can I get an audio book from iTunes onto an iPhone?

Tags: itunes, sync, iphone

I have just purchased an audio book from iTunes on my PC. I synced my iPhone with iTunes successfully, but the audio book hasn't been added to the phone. Why not, and what can I do to get the book onto my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to implicitly tell iTunes to sync audiobooks to your iPhone (see image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to authorize the iphone for use with audible audiobooks first before you can transfer the audiobook there.

have a look here:
http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-ipod-audiobooks/

Answer (score 0):

Right, as thepurplepixel points out, you may have to tell iTunes to sync audiobooks.

Also, if other things are not syncing, you may need to tell iTunes to do so.